# iPhone crash log help, GPUImage/UIScrollView related

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, gpuimage

I'm getting very random bugs that only occur a couple of times a day with heavy testing. I have a `UIScrollView` with some preview images of filter choices, and when the user stops scrolling in this `UIScrollView`, whichever image is highlighted, that respective filter previews gets applied to the image showing in a `UIImageView`. I've provided a crash log below for the respective thread that crashed (not the other threads in the crash log), but if you need more information please let me know.

Any help in understanding this crash log is always appreciated.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000005
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2edbe47e CFGetTypeID + 6
1   CoreVideo                       0x2f5dd114 _getCVPixelBuffer + 12
2   CoreVideo                       0x2f5dd1dc CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow + 4
3   TheApp                          0x00168348 0xe9000 + 521032
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x39b11d3c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x39b1656a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 226
6   TheApp                          0x000f89b6 0xe9000 + 63926
7   TheApp                          0x00168268 0xe9000 + 520808
8   TheApp                          0x00162f8e 0xe9000 + 499598
9   TheApp                          0x000f9638 0xe9000 + 67128
10  TheApp                          0x0017b31c 0xe9000 + 598812
11  TheApp                          0x00179c10 0xe9000 + 592912
12  UIKit                           0x316f2c80 -[UIScrollView _endPanNormal:] + 1536
13  UIKit                           0x31856d0c -[UIScrollView handlePan:] + 116
14  UIKit                           0x318457f4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 192
15  UIKit                           0x316f0a8e -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1134
16  UIKit                           0x31a980ba ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 42
17  UIKit                           0x316b794c _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 216
18  UIKit                           0x316b60ae _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 294
19  UIKit                           0x316ef300 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 768
20  UIKit                           0x316eec26 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 662
21  UIKit                           0x316c3e50 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
22  UIKit                           0x316c251c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7116
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee58fac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee58472 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2ee56c62 __CFRunLoopRun + 626
26  CoreFoundation                  0x2edc1724 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2edc1506 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
28  GraphicsServices                0x33d306ce GSEventRunModal + 134
29  UIKit                           0x3172286c UIApplicationMain + 1132
30  TheApp                          0x001c18e2 0xe9000 + 887010
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x39b26ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the report and then you'll see in frames 3 and 6-11 where in your code the problem is.

Comment: @Kerni Crap, I deleted the crash log from Xcode, but its still in the Console. Is there anyway to symbolicate it now?

Comment: If you have the full report with all headers and footers, save it to a file, drag it into Xcode or manually symbolicate it using the terminal and the `symbolicatecrash` script from Xcode. There is plenty of help on how to do this available.

Comment: Right, but I don't have the binary or .dsym anymore for the archive. Which I was aware is needed to symbolicate. Dragging the .crash file into the Organizer window doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Why don't you have the dsym?! You should **never** delete those, for any version of your app. They come in really handy in situations like this.

Comment: Yeah, I now realize that after doing some research. fml. I just don't like keeping files I dont need.

Comment: Yet you **absolutely** need dSyms. For the next time.

Comment: Generated a new archive (and kept it this time) and installed app on phone again; if I can get it to crash again hopefully this will help!